VSC envelope is not showing on website , please check my code. whats the problem?
please Help. already 3 days trying to find a mistake on my code.
I just start learning coding. Thank you
<div class="left-column">
<div class="Icon">
<i class="fa-sharp fa-thin fa-envelope" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
</div>
<div class="email-address">
<h3> aigul@hi-techintelligentservices.com </h3>
</div>
</div>

I tried many different code for envelope, none of them is working.

do you use any framework ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
